# How to load anotherTableView for every cell that is selected?

Tags: ios, uitableview, switch-statement

I am new to Objective-C/iOS programming so please bear with me for stupid mistakes. I have a Flight Sim app that I am making, that has one tab "Checklists". In the first tblView are the aircraft (eg. B737, A320). Depending on the aircraft pressed, another tblView will load, with different data for each aircraft.

Here is my project --> https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpysl5or954laep/FS%20Companion.zip

I cannot seem to work out how to load the different data. I tried to make an int aircraftNumber, then make an object for each aircraft file. Then do a switch statement using aircraftNumber, and in the switch do a pushViewController. I couldn't seem to create the objects and the indexPath.row successfully.


I hope somebody can help, and that you understood my problem.


Thanks,

Luke

Comment: If I understand: you want to create a tableView, when you click on a row, you display another tableView with data, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but each row loads different data in the second tableView. If you look at the project I think that might help understand it better than I can explain it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the select method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Create a DVC Object
    switch ([indexPath row]) {
        case 0:
        {
            ChecklistsA320Controller * A320Contoller = [[ChecklistsA320Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChecklistsA320Controller" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:A320Contoller animated:YES];
        }
            break;

        case 2:
        {
            Checklists737Controller * B737Controller = [[Checklists737Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"Checklists737Controller" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:B737Controller animated:YES];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But in your case, I think you could improve your architecture. Create only one class "A" with a UITableView which displays data. Then create a class "B" which will create instances of your class "A" and manage your different data.

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean to have class "A" that contains the TableView, and class "B" contains multiple NSArrays for each aircraft, say A320_checklists and B737_checklists, etc ... ?

Comment: Yes, I think you could create a class Aircraft, each aircraft (for example A380) will inherit of Aircraft. Then your class B manages all aircrafts and create instance of class A to display list.